# Javascript: how to clear textboxes and restore their values?

Tags: javascript

I have dozen `textboxes` on my form. On button click I need to clear some of them (not all) and if some conditions are satisfied, I need to restore values in `textboxes`.  How can I do that with less blood?

Comment: Can you use JQuery to do that ? or must be implemented using pure JavaScript ?

Answer (score 1):

This will manipulate your all input depending on condition but you have to call this method on your own

```
  $("form").children("input").each(function(){
    if(condition)
    {$(this).val(this.defaultValue);
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an `.defaultValue` property which you can use like this:

```
txt.onblur = function() {
    alert('restoring default value!');
    this.value = this.defaultValue;
}
​
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AX574/)